# Unable to activate pdfhandler extension for Bluespice/Mediawiki

Tags: php, apache, mediawiki, bluespice

I installed Bluespice on a Ubuntu 16.04 server (same server already has plain Mediawiki installed in a separate directory) and tried to activate the included pdfhandler extension. When I list the installed extensions in the Bluespice Wiki it doesn't show up. The system should have all the necessary requirements, since pdfhandler does work on the mediawiki installation.

**LocalSettings.php**

```
    <?php
# This file was automatically generated by the MediaWiki 1.27.1
# installer. If you make manual changes, please keep track in case you
# need to recreate them later.
#
# See includes/DefaultSettings.php for all configurable settings
# and their default values, but don't forget to make changes in _this_
# file, not there.
#
# Further documentation for configuration settings may be found at:
# https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings

# Protect against web entry
if ( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
    exit;
}

## Uncomment this to disable output compression
# $wgDisableOutputCompression = true;

$wgSitename = "client";

## The URL base path to the directory containing the wiki;
## defaults for all runtime URL paths are based off of this.
## For more information on customizing the URLs
## (like /w/index.php/Page_title to /wiki/Page_title) please see:
## https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL
$wgScriptPath = "/bluespice";

## The protocol and server name to use in fully-qualified URLs
$wgServer = "http://client.somedns.org";

## The URL path to static resources (images, scripts, etc.)
$wgResourceBasePath = $wgScriptPath;

## The URL path to the logo.  Make sure you change this from the default,
## or else you'll overwrite your logo when you upgrade!
$wgLogo = "$wgResourceBasePath/resources/assets/wiki.png";

## UPO means: this is also a user preference option

$wgEnableEmail = false;
$wgEnableUserEmail = true; # UPO

$wgEmergencyContact = "apache@client.somedns.org";
$wgPasswordSender = "apache@client.somedns.org";

$wgEnotifUserTalk = false; # UPO
$wgEnotifWatchlist = false; # UPO
$wgEmailAuthentication = true;

## Database settings
$wgDBtype = "mysql";
$wgDBserver = "localhost";
$wgDBname = "#####";
$wgDBuser = "######";
$wgDBpassword = "######";

# MySQL specific settings
$wgDBprefix = "";

# MySQL table options to use during installation or update
$wgDBTableOptions = "ENGINE=InnoDB, DEFAULT CHARSET=binary";

# Experimental charset support for MySQL 5.0.
$wgDBmysql5 = false;

## Shared memory settings
$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_NONE;
$wgMemCachedServers = [];

## To enable image uploads, make sure the 'images' directory
## is writable, then set this to true:
$wgEnableUploads = true;
$wgUseImageMagick = true;
$wgImageMagickConvertCommand = "/usr/bin/convert";

# InstantCommons allows wiki to use images from https://commons.wikimedia.org
$wgUseInstantCommons = false;

## If you use ImageMagick (or any other shell command) on a
## Linux server, this will need to be set to the name of an
## available UTF-8 locale
$wgShellLocale = "C.UTF-8";

## Set $wgCacheDirectory to a writable directory on the web server
## to make your wiki go slightly faster. The directory should not
## be publically accessible from the web.
#$wgCacheDirectory = "$IP/cache";

# Site language code, should be one of the list in ./languages/data/Names.php
$wgLanguageCode = "de-formal";

$wgSecretKey = "################";

# Changing this will log out all existing sessions.
$wgAuthenticationTokenVersion = "1";

# Site upgrade key. Must be set to a string (default provided) to turn on the
# web installer while LocalSettings.php is in place
$wgUpgradeKey = "#########";

## For attaching licensing metadata to pages, and displaying an
## appropriate copyright notice / icon. GNU Free Documentation
## License and Creative Commons licenses are supported so far.
$wgRightsPage = ""; # Set to the title of a wiki page that describes your license/copyright
$wgRightsUrl = "";
$wgRightsText = "";
$wgRightsIcon = "";

# Path to the GNU diff3 utility. Used for conflict resolution.
$wgDiff3 = "/usr/bin/diff3";

# The following permissions were set based on your choice in the installer
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['createaccount'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit'] = false;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;

## Default skin: you can change the default skin. Use the internal symbolic
## names, ie 'vector', 'monobook':
$wgDefaultSkin = "vector";

# End of automatically generated settings.
# Add more configuration options below.


# This is the main settings file for all BlueSpice extensions and settings
# It will include all files in "$IP/settings.d/" directory
require_once "$IP/LocalSettings.BlueSpice.php";


$wgUserMergeProtectedGroups = array();
$wgUserMergeUnmergeable = array();
$wgMFAutodetectMobileView = true;
$wgMFEnableDesktopResources = true;
$wgShowExceptionDetails = true;

# Pdf previews: 

#require_once "$IP/extensions/PdfHandler/PdfHandler.php";
wfLoadExtension( 'PdfHandler' );
$wgPdfProcessor = "gs";
$wgPdfPostProcessor = $wgImageMagickConvertCommand;
#$wgPdfPostProcessor = "convert";
$wgPdfInfo = "pdfinfo";
$wgPdftoText  = "pdftotext";
$wgPdfOutputExtension  = "jpg";
$wgPdfHandlerDpi  = "150";
```

(The relevant part is at the bottom)